# Adjust WPF window to current screen in multi monitor setup

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, .net-4.8

This method runs in the OnWindow_SizeChanged event.

```
private void UpdateWindowConstraints(Window window)
 {
     if (window != null)
     {
         // Make sure we don't bump the max width and height of the desktop when maximized
         GridLength borderWidth = (GridLength)window.FindResource("BorderWidth");


             if (borderWidth != null)
             {
                 window.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height + borderWidth.Value * 2;

                 window.MaxWidth = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width + borderWidth.Value * 2;
             }
         

     }
 }
```

The issue is that when you move the WPF window to your secondary display, which in most cases will be a larger screen than the primary display, the WPF window's bounds are stuck based on the primary screen's bounds when maximised.

I've adjusted the method to cater to this:

```
private void UpdateWindowConstraints(Window window)
 {
     if (window != null)
     {
         winForms.Screen currentScreen = winForms.Screen.FromHandle(new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle);

         

         // Make sure we don't bump the max width and height of the desktop when maximized
         GridLength borderWidth = (GridLength)window.FindResource("BorderWidth");

         if (currentScreen.Primary)
         {
             if (borderWidth != null)
             {
                 window.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height + borderWidth.Value * 2;

                 window.MaxWidth = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width + borderWidth.Value * 2;
             }
         }
         else
         {
             System.Drawing.Rectangle bounds = currentScreen.Bounds;

             window.MaxHeight = bounds.Height - 300;

             window.MaxWidth = bounds.Width + borderWidth.Value * 2;
         }
     }
 }
```

I use the magic number of 300 to account for the taskbar because no other solutions I've seen to get the taskbar height seem to work..

The issue now is that this only works on my secondary display... Is there any other way to get the max width and height of the current screen including the taskbar? It seems like the width is always fine, even if the secondary display is the smaller screen, I just can't seem to fit the height,  any suggestions will help.

I've tried using SHAppBarMessage as well, and I do get a value back but the window still overlaps the taskbar. The taskbar is not set to auto-hide. And not that SystemParams.WorkArea is only for the primary screen. currentScreen.WorkingArea doesn't account for taskbars.